# parameter in function is null but shown in URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to call an Action from a View.
This is the Html generating the link :

```
 <div class="text-center">
    <a href="/Admin/Refund/AddRefund/@returnLabel.Id" class="btn btn-danger text-white" 
        style="cursor:pointer">
        <i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i>
    </a>
 </div>
```

when i reach the action, the paramter is null

```
public IActionResult AddRefund(int? returnId)
        {
            RefundVM refundVM;
```

but the URL looks correct:
https://localhost:44326/Admin/Refund/AddRefund/11

How is it possible that i can see the parameter in the url but it's null inside the action?
I checked the path many times,
both the View i'm calling from and the action are in the same Admin role.

Any suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: could it be related to the fact i'm calling from a view of one folder to a controller of a different folder?
both under Admin role

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution for this.
At startup.cs
it is defined

```
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{area=UserRole}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
```

so the parameter name HAS to be id and i was using returnId

Comment: Yes, or you can keep the parameter name the same and hit the action at `https://localhost:44326/Admin/Refund/AddRefund?returnId=11` passing the `returnId` as a query string parameter instead of part of the route